# With a for loop, how could I make it so that two objects are being iterated?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Forgive me if the verbiage isn't correct. So I'm working with some JSON data and I want to try and print some columnized output so that two or three of the objects will be printed over each pass. Right now, this would just iterate over one as expected.

```
data = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(["some_command_here"]))

for obj in data:
    print obj['key_a']
```

Output

```
value_a
value_b
value_c
value_d
value_e
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
value_a     value_b     value_c
value_d     value_e
```

Where each group of objects is printed on one row. So first iteration handles value_a, value_b, and value_c, the next one handles value_d, value_e, and value_f is applicable, etc.

How does iteration change in this case? The other thing if it warrants consideration is the number of objects in data is dynamic. Could be 1, could be 5, could be 20+.

Comment: It's not clear from the question which keys you want to group up. Is it "(a, b), (c, d), (e)" or "(a, b, c), (d, e)" or "(a, d), (b, e), (c)"?

Comment: @Mephy I would like to group them up three at a time. My intent is to have a group on one row in the order they are. So (a,b,c), (d,e,f),  so and so forth. I will update my question as well.

Comment: Are you talking about the formatting of the output itself or structuring the data you are extracting differently?

Comment: @QuinnCat What makes them a group?

Comment: @Jerinaw Just the fact that they'd be handled in one iteration - or that's what I would suppose. Pardon me if that was the incorrect term to use.

Comment: @pvg Well, I'm not looking to really touch the structure of data at all. I'm just trying to print multiple keys or values at once.

Comment: Push them onto an array, then print them after the loop. Join the array by whatever you want, then print it. Or even print(obj['key_a'], end=' '), if you're using python 3

Comment: Right but is this really just about printing? Because that need not affect the iteration at all, just only print newlines on every third item.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [itertools grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Your use case would look something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for objs in grouper(data, 3, fillvalue=''):
    print(*objs, sep='     ')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat, here's a procedural one as a generator:

```
def iterate_columns(iterable, columns=4):
    result = []
    for item in iterable:
        result.append(item)
        if len(result) >= columns:
            yield result
            result = []
    if result:
        yield result

your_list = ["value_a", "value_b", "value_c", "value_d", "value_e"]
for row in iterate_columns(your_list, 3):
    print(row)  # feel free to print your data however you want

# prints:
# ['value_a', 'value_b', 'value_c']
# ['value_d', 'value_e']
```

Or a slicing one, again as a generator function:

```
def iterate_columns(iterable, columns=4):
    for i in xrange(0, len(iterable), columns):  # replace with range() on Python 3.x
        yield iterable[i:i+columns]
```

And finally, probably the fastest for use in-place - the same concept using list comprehension:

```
[your_list[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(your_list), 3)]  # replace 3 with number of columns
```